# Spark executor log (stderr) rolling

Tags: apache-spark

I've tried to set configuration properties to rollover stderr log (which is growing and growing)

```
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles","5")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval","minutely")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy","time")
```

or

```
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles","5")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize","100000")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy","size")
```

It doesn't work or it works different than I expect (there is not much documentation about).

For example, I expect that time-based rolling will created new file after every minute (as configured above). However, after that period it still growing.

`mySparkConf = SparkConf()`
`...`
`mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles","5")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize","100000")
mySparkConf.set("spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy","size")`
`...`
`mySparkContext = SparkContext(conf=mySparkConf)
mySparkStreamingContext = StreamingContext(mySparkContext,10)
mySparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("my app").config(conf=mySparkConf).getOrCreate()`

Comment: what is mySparkConf here, is that what you are using to initiate the spark context ?

Comment: @GauravShah edit my post. Please check.

Comment: @GauravShah I have edited my post

Answer (score 3):

You need to change(add some stuff) in two locations. One in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-default.conf` which you need to add these three lines `in each executor`:

```
spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval  daily
spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy  time
spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles  7
```

The other file that you need to change `for each executor` is `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh` add the following lines:

```
SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="$SPARK_WORKER_OPTS -Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=1800 
 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=864000 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy=time 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval=daily 
-Dspark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=7 "

export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS
```

these worked for me.

Comment: I have added this property during spark submit `--conf spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=5 --conf spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy=size --conf spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize=10000` but it is having no effect

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question but still lack of explanation - those properties are not application settings - they are Spark Worker settings, so you must pass them to the Worker instead of setting them in your SparkConf.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the properties in `spark-defaults.conf` located under `install_location/resources/spark/conf/` with below properties:

```
spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles 5
spark.executor.logs.rolling.strategy size
spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxSize 100000
```

Please note that there's MINIMUM_SIZE_BYTES check in the RollingPolicy code, so make sure you are generating enough log (more than 81920 bytes) to roll files.

Ref. https://github.com/dgshep/spark/commit/258e6c3786ed79ab0245bc7b37a5f55eefbf4358